# How do I add brackets within JSON serialization?

Tags: json, go

I am trying to send a post request to a API endpoint. The endpoint does not work without brackets in the JSON data.

```golang
map1: = map[string] map[string] interface {} {}
map2: = map[string] interface {} {}
map2["firstObject"] = "value1"
map2["secondObject"] = "value2"

map1["jsonName"] = map2
b, err: = json.Marshal(map1)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(string(b)) // outputs: {"jsonName":{"firstObject":"value1","secondObject":"value2"}}
```

I need the output to be: `{"jsonName":[{"firstObject":"value1","secondObject":"value2"}]}`

However, I am getting this: `{"jsonName":{"firstObject":"value1","secondObject":"value2"}}`

Comment: I don't know if Go does simplified syntax, but something like `map1["jsonName"] = [map2]`. Basically make an array variable, push `map2` to that array, set `map1` to that array. You aren't wanting to "add brackets", you are wanting `jsonName` to be an array with `map2` as a member of it, rather than `jsonName` being the `map2` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indicated payload is passing a map as the value of jsonName, when the API needs an array of maps.

It may help if you create the inner map first:

```
map2 := map[string]interface{}{
    "firstObject":  "value1",
    "secondObject": "value2",
}
```

Then create your outer map as a map of `string => []interface{}`, giving your key and value:

```
map1 := map[string][]interface{}{
    "jsonName": []interface{}{map2},
}
```

You can do it all in one shot as:

```
map1 := map[string][]interface{}{
    "jsonName": []interface{}{
        map[string]interface{}{
            "firstObject":  "value1",
            "secondObject": "value2",
        },
    },
}
```